# Using ADB pull command in a Java program

Tags: java, android, adb

I can't get the ADB command to work in Java. The adb command works when inputting it directly to the command line. But when running it in Java, I get error

*`Cannot run program "adb -s shell": CreateProcess error=2,file not found`*

What is the proper syntax for running Windows Command line from Java?
The adb command `"adb devices"` works in the Java application.  The command I'm trying to run is `"adb pull sdcard/Download/symmetri.txt C:/Users/myUsername/Downloads/Sources"`, which works in the command prompt, but not from within the Java application. My code is:

```
public void FilePush() {
            try{

    String androidFilePath = "sdcard/Download/symmetri.txt ";
    String windowsFilePath = "C:\\Users\\myUsername\\Downloads\\Sources\"";

        List<String> cmd = new LinkedList<>();
        cmd.add("adb -s shell");
        cmd.add("adb");
        cmd.add("pull");
        cmd.add(androidFilePath);
        cmd.add(windowsFilePath);

        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = builder.start();


    }
catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

I also tried without  `adb -s shell"` and with

```
String androidFilePath = "\"/storage/sdcard0/Download/symmetri.txt\"";
String windowsFilePath = "\"C:\\Users\\myUsername\\Downloads\\Sources\\"";
```

But got the same error

Comment: Sounds like a path problem.  Try specifying the full path to ADB.

Comment: I added   ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\myUsername\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe","devices");                                                                                          
  and it succesfully shows devicess, however I'm still unsuccesful with doing the pull commands. Is there a way to get the syntax of a filepath? Do I need to put the Device ID somewhere in the path?

Comment: You're missing a starting / on the android filepath.  Basically whatever you use on the command line to make it work should be matched exactly, just with the \ characters escaped

Comment: `The adb command works when inputting it directly to the command line.` Which adb command? When talking about a command please always include the full command. Please edit your question and add this command.

Comment: sorry I forgot, it's "adb pull sdcard/Download/symmetri.txt C:/Users/myUsername/Downloads/Sources". I can get "adb devices" to work in the Java application, and the former command only works in the commando prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line

```
cmd.add("adb -s shell");
```

as you don't want `shell` but `pull`.

Answer (score 0):

Thx to the helpful people here, I finally got it to work! I first needed to run adb.exe as a command, before I could run any adb commands. I needed to remove `("adb -s shell")` from my list of commands. I was trying to acces a file in the external storage instead of the internal one which needs root access
(Although I have no clue why I can acces the exact same file in a Command prompt window without permitting root acces). If you want to access external files, add root access with

`adb root`

Full code that works for anyone who might face the same issue :

```
public void FilePush() {
        try{

        String androidFilePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myapp/files/myfile.txt";

        String windowsFilePath = "C:\\Users\\myUsername\\Downloads\\Sources";

        List<String> cmd = new LinkedList<>();

        cmd.add("C:\\Users\\myUsername\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe");
        cmd.add("pull");
        cmd.add(androidFilePath);
        cmd.add(windowsFilePath);

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
      

        String line = "null";



        pb.redirectErrorStream(true); // can use these 2 line if you want to see output or errors in file.
         pb.redirectOutput(new File("C:\\Users\\myUsername\\Downloads\\Sources\\logs.txt"));

        Process p = pb.start();

        while(p == null)
            Thread.sleep(1000);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+)(\\s+)(device)");
        Matcher matcher;


        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.matches(pattern.pattern())) {
                matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                if (matcher.find()) ;
            }

        }

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your while loop is busy waiting which is a bad programming style. Better just use `p.waitFor()`. Also don't ferget to check the exit code of `p` if an error occurred.